# Conversión de una consulta a código ORM Django

Tags: django, postgresql, orm, django-smart-selects

Necesito cargar en un select solamente todos los grupos que tengan datos asociados al auth_group_permissions.

El codigo en POSTGRESQL:

```
select id from auth_group where id in (select group_id from auth_group_permissions group by group_id)
```

Comment: Hola William, puedes mostrar tu query actual y qué error está presentando.  Es importante que publiques un __[mcve]__.

Comment: Ya encontré la solución te la comparto. Disculpa que soy nuevo por aquí.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Contesta tu pregunta y en cuanto puedas, márcala como aceptada.

Comment: Listo, gracias por la ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí esta la solución para poder obtener solos los grupos que esten asociados con permisos.

```
Group.objects.filter(id__in = Permission.objects.filter().order_by().distinct().values_list('group__id',flat=True))
```